# Solving a quadratic complex equation

Tags: analysis

What is the approach to solving this equation?
$$
iz^2 + 2(1 − i)z + 2i + 2(\sqrt{3} − 1) = 0
$$
I do not think that I need the complete solution. Just the approach on how to do it. Please only help if you are 100% sure about your answer.

Thank you,

Comment: If you are trying to find $z$, and $i$ denotes a square root of $-1$, then my approach would be to plug the coefficients into a widely-known formula for the roots of a quadratic equation.

Comment: Maybe start by dividing both sides by $i$ (equivalently, multiply both sides by $-i).$ Then to see that everything is legitimate by the rules you know hold for complex numbers, I recommend going through the steps of completing the square: Half of the coefficient of $z$ is $i-1,$ so you want to add $(i-1)^2 = -2i$ to both sides and then $\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is my idea, just a set up as you requested: Multiply by $-i$ to get $z^2+(-2-2i)z+2-2i(\sqrt{3}-1)=0$ Keeping the $z$ terms on the left, we have $z^2+(-2-2i)z=-2+2i(\sqrt{3}-1)$ Completing the square: $(z-1-i)^2=-2+2i(\sqrt{3}-1)+(-1-i)^2$ When you work out left hand side and setting $z-1-i=t$ we get the equation $t^2=-2+2i\sqrt{3}$ Can you figure out the argument and modulus of that complex number on the right and go from there to extract the roots for $t$? (Got to go now :) )

Comment: Thank you @imranfat

|t| = 4 and Arg(t) = 2pi/3

Roots are:

2(cos pi/3 + i sin pi/3)
2(cos 4pi/3 + i sin 4pi/3)

but this would be solving for t not for z. How do I go back to z?

Comment: I substituted and got z = 2+(sqrt(3)+1)i and z = (1-sqrt(3))i. Is this correct?

Comment: You can plug in these solutions and see...You applied DeMoivre's which is what I would do too.

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked. Thank you so much imranfat. Just the set up was so helpful.